# Make an Ajax call to plug-in controller

Tags: javascript

I am trying to send data to my plug-in controller using jquery $.post() method.
here is my form:

```
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="testForm">
  {{ csrfInput() }}
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="test/test">
  <button type="submit">Test</button>
</form>
```

and this is my js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.csrfTokenName = "{{ craft.config.csrfTokenName|e('js') }}";
   window.csrfTokenValue = "{{ craft.request.csrfToken|e('js') }}";
</script>
<script>
$("#testForm").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = [];
    data["test"] = "test";
    data[csrfTokenName] = csrfTokenValue;
    $.post('/', data, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
});
</script>
```

The console keeps logging "400 Bad Request".
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a route via action param otherwise Craft has no idea where to route the request. Your `data` variable only only contains

```
data = [
    'test' => 'test',
    TOKEN_NAME => TOKEN_VALUE
]
```

and nothing else

You need to include `action => plugin-handle/controller-id/function-name`

You can see a working example at [basic ajax how to](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/24166/basic-ajax-how-to/24167#24167)